# A mathematical rebus. Find the hidden phrase!

Tags: mathematics, rebus

*What does the following [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus) represent?*

$\ \ \ |ly| \ \neq$

Comment: I must quibble with the accepted answer. I would've said the rebus represented "Absolutely not equal". If the intended answer was "Absolutely not", it should have been ended with a "$\neg$" or a "$\sim$".

Comment: I'd used a similar Rebus with !|ly| since ! denotes complement or Not A.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phrase would be

> Absolutely not

Comment: I must quibble with this accepted answer. I would've said the rebus represented "Absolutely not equal". If the intended answer was "Absolutely not", it should have been ended with a "$\neg$" or a "$\sim$".

Comment: @Deepak FWIW I agree with you. I thought it might actually be "(answer) nothing" but that seemed a bit too specific.

Answer (score 12):

I would say the answer should be "Absolutely not equal".

For "Absolutely not", I would've constructed this rebus:

$\ \ \ |ly| \ \neg$ or $\ \ \ |ly| \ \sim$

Comment: I |ly| concur.  ≠ ≠ ¬

Comment: This answer is better than the other one by Will.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to Will's answer,

> if the RHS isn't nothing (but what it is isn't specified) and the LHS is absolute-ly,

then surely,

> it can be absolutely anything!